# Google Mock for NonVirtual and Private Functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, c++14, googlemock

I'm attempting to write Mocks for Private / Non Virtual / Static functions and come across a way to do the same.

Here is how it looks like..

Lets assume that I have a `class A` which needs to be mocked and used inside `class UsingA`. The definition of both classes looks like

```
class A
{
   friend class UsingA;
    int privateFn() {}
public:
    int nonVirtual() {}
};
// The UsingA class
class UsingA {
    A  &a1;
public:
    UsingA(A & _a1) : a1(_a1) {} 
    int CallFn() {
        return a1.nonVirtual();
    }
    int CallFn2() {
        return a1.privateFn();
    }
};
```

I know that Mocks are meant for generating the behavior of the class and while creating Mocks, we need to derive from the original class.

However, to Mock the behavior I decided not to derive from the original class, instead comment the `class A` and generate a Mock class with the same Name i.e `class A`. 
Here is how my mock class looks like

```
// Original class A is commented / header file removed
class A  {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(nonVirtual, int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(privateFn, int());
};
```

And my tests are usual mock tests

```
TEST(MyMockTest, NonVirtualTest) {
    A mstat;
    UsingA ua(mstat);

    EXPECT_CALL(mstat, nonVirtual())
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(Return(100));

    int retVal = ua.CallFn();

    EXPECT_EQ(retVal,100); 

}

TEST(MyMockTest, PrivateTest) {
    A mstat;
    UsingA ua(mstat);

    EXPECT_CALL(mstat, privateFn())
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(Return(100));

    int retVal = ua.CallFn2();

    EXPECT_EQ(retVal,100); 

}
```

And everything works fine and I'm able to test `UsingA` by this mock.

Question is.

This looks easier and serves the purpose, still I haven't seen this kind of examples while browsing for google mock examples. Is there anything that would go wrong if I do this?

Honestly, I didn't find any.

NOTE: Folks, I'm using `friend` for demonstration only. My actual use case is totally different. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The wrong is that you are not testing real code, because of that:

- comment the class A
- generate a Mock class with the same name

These operations alter the code under test.

An example what can go wrong:

1. Change return type: `long nonVirtual` in Mock - previously was `int`
2. Test that on, let say, `nonVirtual() == 0xFF'FFFF'FFFF` (which is bigger than `INTMAX`) some action is being done
3. Forget to change in real `A` - so real `UsingA` have branch that is tested but never reachable in real code

An example code:

```
class A  {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(nonVirtual, long()); // change
    MOCK_METHOD0(privateFn, int());
};
void UsingA::processA()
{
     if (a.nonVirtual() > VERY_BIG_NUMBER)
     {
         throw runtime_error("oops");
     }
}
TEST_F(UsingATest, throwOnVeryBigNumber)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(aMock, nonVirtual()).WillOnce(Return(VERY_BIG_NUMBER + 1));
    ASSERT_THROW(objectUndertTest.processA());
}
```

But real `A` did not change - so we test non reachable code in UsingA class:

```
class A  {
public:
    int nonVirtual(); // not changed
    ...
};
```

The best solution is (in order):

1. To test in isolation you have to isolate classes - so to use dependency injection (virtual functions etc, base interfaces, etc...) - this is sometimes called [London School of TDD](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/London-school-TDD)
2. Test both classes `A` and `UsingA` w/o any stubbing - test them together in one testcase - thus you test real code - this is called [Detroit Shool of TDD](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Detroit-school-TDD)
3. Separate by template code with good restriction on interface - this approach is most similar to yours:

Regarding 3 - you might use something like this:

```
template <class T = A>
class UsingA {
    T  &a1;
public:
    UsingA(T & _a1) : a1(_a1) {} 
    long CallFn() {
        using ANonVirtualResult = std::invoke_result_t<&T::nonVirtual>;
        static_assert(std::is_same<long, ANonVirtualResult>::value);
        return a1.nonVirtual();
    }
    ...
};
```

And in test:

```
class UsingATest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
       StrictMock<AMock> aMock;
       using ClassUnderTest  = UsingA<AMock>;       
       ClassUnderTest objectUnderTest{aMock};
};
 TEST_F(UsingATest,  useNonVirtual)
 {
        const auto VALUE = 123456;
        EXPECT_CALL(aMock, nonVirtual()).WillOnce(Return(VALUE));
        ASSERT_EQ(VALUE, objectUnderTest.CallFn());
 }
```

You might note that some assumption about `A` might be tested during compilation as `static_assert` or via some SFINAE technics (more complicated).

Actually, there are [examples with template code in googlemock](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods) as workaround for mocking classes w/o virtual functions.

Comment: Hello.. Thanks for your answer. As per my experience we don't mock a class to test the class that is mocked. We mock a class so that I can test a class which is using the Mocked class. not sure how the functionality matters in this case as anyway Mocks are not calling original implementation unless explicitely called.

Comment: I assumed A is mocked class, UsingA is A client? Isn't that the case here?

Comment: Hello Yes that's the case `UsingA` is using the `MockA` I understand what you're trying to say about what I'm doing wrong, but the intention of my original question was to check if its really a bad idea, because i can code my MockA to return anything which might generate a situation similar to what you've mentioned in  you answer

Comment: Maybe not "really bad" idea - but it has "cons" mentioned in my answer. Simple speaking - such "manual" replacing types between code under test and unit test code might be source of incompatibility problems that is hard to detect  - because your tests do not see real code.

Comment: You might see in https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods that trick with templates is mentioned in gmock doc

Answer (score 2):

We use your type of using mocks inside a few of our test projects to check callbacks on a larger class that we pass along using dependency injection. In our case, the methods are declared virtual.

In your case, they are not. Your mock implementation would *hide* the original implementation - if there was any. So I don't think there's an issue here.